# Naming Drupal 7 template files based on url

Tags: drupal, templates

If I have a page whose url alias is "/api/user/create", how can I name a template file based on the url such as "page-api-user-create.tpl.php".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to name it:

```
page--api--user--create.tpl.php
```

(note double dashes in the file name).

See http://drupal.org/node/1089656 for more info.

Comment: Can this be used for node aliases?

Comment: As explained on the page I have linked above, for nodes you can use following templates: node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php

Comment: That's type/nodeid, I mean node url alias.

Comment: No, it's not possible with aliases. nids are constant, aliases could be changed in any way you want and at any time, even incidentally, it wouldn't make sense then.

Comment: Well, actually, unless you define your own hook suggestions in relevant preprocess function, then probably yes, you could have them. See http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a page level template file to reflect the url, as was explained by Maciej Zgazdaj.

To do the same with a node level template file you have to add this to your template.php file:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

    $url = str_replace("-", "", $variables['node_url']);
    $urlParts = explode("/", $url);
    unset($urlParts[0]);

    if($urlParts[1] !== false) {
    $out = array();
    $sug = "node";

    foreach($urlParts as $val) {
        $sug .= "__".$val;
        $out[] = $sug;
    }

    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 
        array_merge($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], $out);

    }
}
```

Replace YOURTHEME with .. well your theme. Check the offered suggestions with devel_themer.